# Can I install Unreal Engine 4 on my machine?

Tags: installation

Good Evening, I have a little problem. I have learnt basics of C++ and I really like the language and want to discover Unreal Engine. However, I don't know if my machine is powerful enough. I know many people already asked that before me, but I would be really happy if someone responses to me. Anyways, these are my laptop parametres:

- Procesor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz (12 CPUs), ~2.2GHz
  RAM: 8GB
- I probably have 2 graphic cards, or I don't know, parametres:

1. Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630, 4GB, VRAM 128MB
2. NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, 8GB, VRAM 4GB

- SSD disk with the capacity of 128GB total, I can have about 30GB free
- HDD disk with the capacity of 1TB

I don't wont to use the computer only for Unreal Engine, but I also won't develop high-level games, I just want to learn main concepts of the engine and develop some small games.

If there are any other parametres which you need to know, no problem, just write which and I will try to find them. Also note that I am new to Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, so sorry if this question doesn't match to topics allowed in this site. I posted it on Stack Overflow but it gave me a message saying that I should use Stack Exchange for these questions. So I hope it will match here :)

Someone also responded to me why don't I just compare it to some docs about the requirements for UE. I can do it for sure, but some parametres were okay and some not, for instance I found that it's good that to have SSD disc, but I don't know how important is to have large RAM.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may see the requirements in
[Hardware and Software Specifications](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Basics/RecommendedSpecifications/index.html).

They are rather modest:

```
Operating System : Windows 10 64-bit
Processor : Quad-core Intel or AMD, 2.5 GHz or faster
Memory : 8 GB RAM
Video Card/DirectX Version : DirectX 11 or DirectX 12 compatible graphics card
```

Your computer should be right for running Unreal Engine.

Comment: Yes, I knew about that document, but as I said, I didn't know whether 2.2GHz is ok instead of recommended 2.5GHz or not and so on. So you say it should be okay, nice, thanks!

Comment: The [i7-8750H Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134906/intel-core-i7-8750h-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html) can Turbo itself up to  4.10 GHz in case of heavy usage.

Comment: Those are the requirements just for the Editor.  Anything you make in the editor will also have it's own requirements.

Comment: @harrymc And that's good or bad? That means that the laptop works faster or it may crash? Or both?

Comment: It means that the laptop can do better than 2.5GHz without any problem. You have a good CPU, use it without worry.

Comment: Done :) And what do you think about @Ramhound 's comment?

Comment: (@Ramhound: Correct me if I'm wrong.) I think he meant that whatever program you create that uses Unreal Engine will have different requirements during runtime. I would think that they would be less demanding than during development.

Comment: Okay, and should I save the files created in Unreal to HDD or SSD? I used SSD mainly for applications and HDD mainly for files like songs, text documents and so on.

Comment: @Creighton - That's entirely your decision.  As with anything that requires you to compile code.  It will be faster on a SSD.

Comment: For small files I don't think it matters much. SSD might be quieter...

Comment: Yeah, that will probably depend on the project's size. For smaller SSD and for bigger HDD as I don't have so much space on SSD.